# ¿Como puedo asignar automáticamente una variable de tipo clase en unity una cada ves que hago una instancia?

Tags: unity3d

Hola lo que necesito es saber como puedo asignar en cada instancia de un objeto este asigne una variable de forma automática de tipo clase.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;`
public class HealthBarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Controller Player;
    public Image Health;
    public float Scale;`

    void Start () {}
    void Update(){}
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Health.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Player.Health / 100, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

ya la tengo asignada manualmente pero, cada ves que elimino el objeto `Player` la variable de su clase deja de estar asignada y quiero que al volver a hacer una instancia de este se asigne de nuevo.